# google cloud platform for image fetching from url

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, imagedownload

I need to download 1 million images(approx) from different web sources using image url and store it in google cloud platform using python. Is there any specific services available in google cloud platform for faster download with storage option.

Comment: Is this still open? Need some details: Are the image URLs in a database in google cloud? Or are they streamed as a result of a crawler bot running on a GCE instance? Do you have budget or you are limited to free tier? If not still open, what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/). Make sure you create buckets on the region closest to your user's location. Sample POST:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=media&name=myObject
```

1M images can potentially be a lot of bandwith. [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program) on Cloud Storage can help you control access to the buckets like giving time-limited read/write access to a specific resource.

Here is the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/), the [API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/), and [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#uploading).